# Docker container built for Python/Kivy crashes when starting to run

Tags: python, docker, kivy, x11, sdl-2

I’m trying to run a GUI application written in Python and Kivy language in Debian/Jesse, but have run into an issue when trying to run the container.
So, I wrote the Docker file, built the image and getting this issue when the container starts to run halfway through. By the looks of it, the problem is related to building a connection between host machine and the container for SDL2 /X11. Would be very much appreciated if someone could give some ideas on this. I have shared the my Dockerfile and error below.
Thanks in advance.

Dockerfile -

```
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 

libsdl2-dev 
libsdl2-image-dev
libsdl2-mixer-dev 
libsdl2-ttf-dev 

pkg-config 
libgl1-mesa-dev 
libgles2-mesa-dev 
python-setuptools 
libgstreamer1.0-dev 
git-core
python-dev 
gcc 
python-pip 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly 
gstreamer1.0-alsa 
gstreamer1.0-omx 
xclip
libmtdev-dev 
python-pygame

RUN pip install cython

RUN pip install git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git@master

ENV XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000

ADD animate.py /

CMD [“python”,“animate.py”]
```

Error log is below -

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/dockTest $ docker container run kivydock
[WARNING] [Config ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 20)
[WARNING] [Config ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[INFO ] [Logger ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-01-16_0.txt
[INFO ] [Kivy ] v1.10.1.dev0, git-00c161d, 20180115
[INFO ] [Python ] v2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04)
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO ] [Factory ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO ] [Image ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO ] [Text ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO ] [OSC ] using for socket
[INFO ] [Window ] Provider: sdl2([‘window_egl_rpi’] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name bcm
File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/init.py”, line 59, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py”, line 12, in 
from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - RuntimeError: No available video device
File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/init.py”, line 67, in core_select_lib
cls = cls()
File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py”, line 140, in init
super(WindowSDL, self).init()
File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/init.py”, line 960, in init
self.create_window()
File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py”, line 272, in create_window
self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
File “kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx”, line 93, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
File “kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx”, line 66, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die

x11 - ImportError: No module named window_x11
File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/init.py”, line 59, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: you need to mount your X11 folders from the host system onto the docker image ... in my experience its a big pain in the ass to get kivy to run in a container ... you might be able to get it working by using some vnc stuff but its a big pain and really fragile...

Comment: Cheers @JoranBeasley

Comment: @JoranBeasley can you ellaborate a bit more on that? besides being a pia, were you able to make it work? I'm already having some graphics made inside the container to show up on the host, but when it comes to kivy it's not finding any suitable window provider according to the logs. Thank you.

Comment: I did get it working ... but it was not reliable and there was some crazy amounts of weird lag ... it just sucked I think it took like 3 days to get working ... and then it just broke after like a week or something and I couldnt be bothered to get it working again (It would be really great if they(kivy) could provide an x11 version with vnc docker image, or provide a great step by step way to solve this)